# How to generate a 'dynamic' member by codedom?

Tags: c#, dynamic, field, member, codedom

I want to generate such code by codedom, like this

```
public class Class1
{
    private dynamic mDynamicObject;
    public dynamic DynamicObject
    {
        get { return mDynamicObject; }
        set { mDynamicObject = value; }
    }   
}
```

And i want to use codedom of CodeMemberField to declare the "mDynamicObject", but the type of dynamic i don't know how to declare this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CodeMemberField dynamicMember = new CodeMemberField ( );
dynamicMember.Name = dynamicMemberName;
dynamicMember.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
dynamicMember.Type = new CodeTypeReference ( "dynamic" );
operationCodeType.Members.Add ( dynamicMember );
```